# Execute all functions from module

Tags: python

```
class MyClass(object):
    def fn():
        return 1

for i in [method for method in dir(inspect) if callable(getattr(inspect, method))]:
    print i(MyClass) // Error here
```

Error: **TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

If i change print statement to:

```
print "%s(MyClass)" % i
```

this simply print:

```
ArgInfo(MyClass)
and so on...
```

Comment: Your ``i`` is a string. You already have code in there with which you "convert" that string to a function.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer, I don't get it. You mean `print "%s(MyClass)" % i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dir(module)` returns a list of names (strings) defined in the module, not the actual functions or values. To get those, use `getattr`, which you already use for the `callable` check.

```
for name in dir(your_module):
    might_be_function = getattr(your_module, name)
    if callable(might_be_function):
        print might_be_function(your_parameters)
```

Of course, it might still be the case that the function is not applicable to the given parameters, so you might want to check this first, or wrap in in a `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to call all methods by name like that?

```
class C1:
    def f1(self):
        print('f1---')
    def f2(self):
    print('f2---')

inspect = C1()
for i in [method for method in dir(inspect) if callable(getattr(inspect, method))]:
    getattr(inspect, i)()
```